# jQuery gallery not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-9, cufon

I created image gallery for one of my clients, http://ianespinoza.com/, and it worked fine everywhere, until IE9 came out.

I just found out that gallery does not work in IE 9 - if you click on different thumbnails it does not change the main image.

The site is built in Wordpress I do have the latest Wordpress version installed. It comes with jQuery 1.6.1.

Also, the site is using Cufon and client has reported that it is not rendering correctly either.

Any help in resolving this will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken just the gallery portion out onto it's own page to isolate it? I'd start there, as it would make debugging it easier and also confirm there isn't a conflict with anything else on the site in IE9's mind.

Comment: what sorts of things IE9 might be conflicting with?

Answer (score 1):

Use Firebug in Firefox or Dev tools in Safari, IE or Chrome to check and debug your javascript.

Your version of CuFon is broken in IE9; update it. You want 1.09i.